# Not sure how to implement fill_between in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot financial data, and everything is looking good until I add a fill, which I want to be between a line and the top of the graph. I'm doing something very wrong, but I don't know what. I receive this error: "TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the
ed types according to the casting rule ''safe''"

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
import mysql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

db = mysql.connect()
cursor = db.cursor()

contractID = input('Enter contract ID: ')

prices = []
x      = []

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM prices WHERE ContractID = %s' % contractID)

for i in range(0, cursor.rowcount):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    price = row[2] # Changing this to price = int(row[2]) fixes the problem. See comments.
    prices.append(price)
    x.append(i)

plt.fill_between(x, 100, prices) # TODO: This doesn't work. Everything else works if I remove this line.
plt.plot(prices)
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.show()
```

EDIT: I'd love to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, but when I attempt to do so, the example works. I don't know how to reproduce the error.

Here's my working attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []

for i in range(0, 49):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i)

plt.fill_between(x, 100, y) # This works fine now
plt.plot(x, '#000000')
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It would help tremendously if you provided a [mcve], which is runnable and does not depend on some database.

Comment: When I create an example that fulfills those guidelines, the fill works. So I'm extra confused as to what's going wrong.

Comment: See that's the point of a mcve. In this case the example surely has to be a little more complex than what the updated code shows. Check for datatypes in the resulting lists. Hardcode the output lists (only use some of the elements). Check the output query for unusual things like empty fields etc.

Comment: I simplified the code as much as I could so that the error is still reproduced. All the values in prices are from 0 to 99, as they should be, which is probably why it plots as it should. There are 1,410 values altogether, in case that matters. I don't understand why it plots okay, but it doesn't fill okay.

Comment: No, you have one example which is not runnable, but reproduces the error (according to you, nobody can verify); and you have one example which does not reproduce the error - and is hence not useful. See what happens if you only take 10 rows from the dataset. If this reproduces the error, hardcode those lists in the example. If this works fine, find 10 rows which do reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is where I get confused. If I reduce the list to ten values, they're all 7. If I rewrite the code to use a list of ten 7's, it works. I don't know how to rewrite this in a way that reproduces the error for anyone but me.

Comment: This fixes it: "price = int(row[2])"

Still no clue why it plots without casting but fails to fill.

Comment: Well, I did say "Check for datatypes in the resulting lists", didn't I? The reason it works for `plot` is that something like `plt.plot(["apple", "banana", "cherry"])` is actually valid. While filling between those categories makes no sense. So `plot` accepts strings, but `fill_between` does not.

Comment: Apologies. I'm a noob.